# Qsub job runs but doesn't write to file

Tags: qsub

I am running a parallelised code on an SGE cluster, via the qsub command.

The code (which compiled successfully on the system on which it is supposed to run) is meant to take a file of input values, minimise some function of those values, and then output the new values to the same input file.

The job executes succesfully (code 0), and runs for about 40 minutes of walltime: but nothing is written to the input file.

This is my script to submit the jobs:

```
#!/bin/bash
#PBS -V
#PBS -l select=1:ncpus=20:mpiprocs=20,walltime=02:00:00 
#PBS -o some/path
#PBS -e some/path
#PBS -q smp
#PBS -m ae
#PBS -M user@username.com
#PBS -P Name
#PBS -I
#PBS -N minMg-1


module load gcc/5.1.0
module load chpc/openmpi/1.10.2/gcc-5.1.0


mpirun -np 20 $SRCDIR/myexecutable args < inputfile.inp
```

I can't see why the thing executes successfully, but doesn't write to inputfile.inp. Strangely, I also don't get the standard ".o" and ".e" files, either. I am sure my mistake may be obvious to someone in the know! Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure your system lets you read and write using the same file. Have you tried `foo -args < inputfile.inp >outputfile.out` and see if what you want ends up in `outputfile.out`?

Comment: Thanks so much @Spacedman! I must have been attacked by math symbol dyslexia! I shall swap it round the right way and see if it works :-D

Comment: Sorry I deleted my original comment cos I didnt notice you were trying to read/write to the same file. see updated comment above...#

Comment: Thanks! I wondered where it had gone! I also wondered why my attempt to fix it that way didn't work :-D Thanks for what looks like a great idea...it probably is that the system doesn't like the input file being the output file! I will try what you suggest...awesome! Kudos.